# How to train Yolov8 without its auto augmentation

Tags: yolo, yolov8

I've been trying to train a YOLOv8 model and noticed it applies augmentation automatically.
I'm using the command:
`yolo train --resume model=yolov8n.pt imgsz=480 data=data.yaml epochs=20 cache=True workers=2`
Adding an argument `--augment=False` does not seem to work, as the output of the training still indicates it is applying augmentations:

[image]

From what I've seen there should be some file that I can edit that will prevent this but I have no idea where to find it (I didn't clone the repo, only installed ultralytics through pip).

Answer (score 2):

Some augmentations are applied by default to increase dataset diversity and improve model performance. To set the augmentation parameters,
look for the configuration file **ultralytics/cfg/default.yaml**.
To find out where pip installs packages, check 'Location' as the output of `python -m pip show pip`. It can be something like this: */usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages*.

As for **albumentations**, there are some integrated directly into the dataset loader code and are not part of the configuration file. In most of cases, you don't need to get rid of them. More information in this answer: https://github.com/ultralytics/ultralytics/issues/4254#issuecomment-1671960129

The argument `--augment=False` is not active in the training mode, it is responsible for applying image augmentation to prediction sources.